# Gmail: why are all my messages "partially" labelled?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

When I select a label, and "select all N messages in X label", *all possible* labels are partially selected. To be clear, this doesn't happen unless I select all messages in a label. *None* of the messages selected have any other label; to put it another way, each message has only one label, the one with the full check, and no others.

If I just select all messages on the page, I don't have this problem.

[image]

I've manually deselected all the tags to wipe the messages, and when they're reselected, none of them are partially selected again.

Aside from the obvious question, "why?", is there a way to fix this without manually deselecting a bunch of tags?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking why _some_ of the other labels in your list there have a dash instead of a checkmark or a blank box? That indicates that _some_ of the messages you've selected _also_ have the indicated label. Please [edit] your question to clarify; you appear to be missing a few words.

Comment: That's just the thing: *none* of these messages have any other label when viewed individually.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  You probably already know this, but GMail sometimes shows e-mails as having fewer labels than they really have.  This sometimes happens when you do e-mail searches based on labels.

Comment: Another possibility (again probably not, but worth mentioning):  You may have hidden labels.  To check, click the box beside each label and look at "In message list: / Show / Hide" .

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I do have hidden labels, but these messages have every single label I have available. Plus, they only appear checked when I select multiple "pages" at once. I don't have this problem if I only select the 100 messages on the first page.